# Creating shapes with inverted corvers

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a shape design and I have been able to achieve most of what I need. The issue is the shape I created I need it to be covered in a gradient and not a solid color.
I have attached a copy of the HTML and CSS code below:

```css
.chopped {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1), rgba(255, 255, 0, .2));
}

.inner-round {
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1) 5%)
}

.inner-round1 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1) 5%)
}
```

```html
<div class="chopped">
  <div class="inner-round"></div>
  <div class="inner-round1"></div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the linear gradient overlay the shape below, above it.

Answer (score 0):

if you can create one more div after/outside the .chopped => add "absolute:position" with "top:0 left:0" on new ".overlay" after the ".chopped".

```html
<div class="chopped">
  <div class="inner-round"></div>
  <div class="inner-round1"></div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

```css
.chopped {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1), rgba(255, 255, 0, .2)); */
}

.inner-round {
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1) 5%);
}

.inner-round1 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1) 5%);
}

.overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1), rgba(255, 255, 0, .2));
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for mask:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue);
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle 50px at bottom left ,#0000 97%,#000 ) left,
    radial-gradient(circle 50px at top    right,#0000 97%,#000 ) right;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: @JoshNomso don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue